# Custom HttpInterceptor - How to return a never-resolving Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm following [this article](https://hackernoon.com/global-http-error-catching-in-angular-4-3-9e15cc1e0a6b) about how to implement global error handling in my Angular application via a custom `HttpInterceptor` class.

The important part is this implementation of `intercept()`:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // do error handling here
      }
    });
  }
```

What I can't figure out how to do is if I catch an error here how can I have the `intercept()` function return an Observable that will never resolve?

I tried changing `next.handle.do()` to `next.handle.catch()` which lets me return an Observable but I want to use `Observable.never` to return an observable that will never resolve but it expects me to return a type of `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` and it won't let me cast the `NeverObservable` to that type.

Is there a way to get the functionality I want?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to return a Never.  Maybe some context would help.

Comment: @meteorainer I'm trying to have a warning show in the UI if an Http 500 or 503 error happens and I want to stop the error from propagating down to the service or component because, for reasons, they will handle the error warning message if it's an error code not equal to 500/503. I'm essentially trying to filter out 500 and 503 responses in the interceptor.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a customer error service, inject it into the interceptor constructor and call a subject on the error handling part, something like `errorService.errorSubject.next(error);`.  In your component inject the service and subscribe to it, just to catch up the error detail.  `errorDeliver.errorSubject().subscribe(error => { ... })`

Comment: @DanielC.this would be possible but it doesn't take care of the part where the failed Http request will still propagate down to the service/component.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return a never.  Return an empty.  They auto complete which you want because never will hang around in memory until the page the ondestory event.  Anything in a loop that returns a 500/503 will just pile up.

```
if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
   if (err.status === 503 || err.status ===500) {
    // do handling. message or whatever
        return Observable.empty();
   }
}
```

Comment: It won't let me return an empty because it's expecting a return value of type `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're limited by the return type fro m `intercept` that you can't change? If you can change it just make:

```
intercept(...): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | Observable<never>
```

If you can't do this then i `catchError()` just return an Observable that never completes:

```
catchError(() => new Observable())
```

Note that you might be creating memory-leaks.

Comment: Ya you are absolutely going to create mem leaks that way. Those observables will hang around for the entire session.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the chain is unsubscribed at some point it won't make any memory leaks.

Comment: Possibly, but you relying on code to manually unsubscribe which probably only happens during the OnDestroy lifecycle event unless someone is specifically coding for garbage collection.